# Negative rep sum displayed out of sync

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

I'd like to report what I think to be a bug with the new vote/unvote showing system.

Right now my rep history looks like:

[image: rep history]

And the corresponding present up/down vote status is:

[image: present up/down status]

Before I had +2 and accepted.

So, **the `sum = -25` is right, but the history is out of sync**, I think it's missing to show a undownvote.

Comment: Also note that your screenshot says "2 events", but shows three...

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: Thanks, I didn't noticed that, anyway it seems that this was a known and next-to-be-fixed bug :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.  The way we roll up "cancelled" activity (e.g. upvote/unupvote) means we groups the events up and strip them.  Previously, the time ranges passed to the ajax call to get that post detail were passing the dates of *that event range*, which the cancellation activity may have fallen outside the range of.  We'll now pass the start/end of the *day*, since that's what's rolled up - and that -2 in your case will go away.

Comment: Either you already knew about this or you're *really* fast

Comment: @Ben - This was a new one, but I am (unfortunately) intimately familiar with all code related to rep at the moment :)